# PHP Class Updating Array - How to make more efficient

Tags: php, arrays, class

I have the following code and I was wondering how I can edit this so that I can update the array with multiple values with one call of:

```
$var->updateArray("Value 1", "Value2", "Value 3", and so on.... );
```

My current code at the moment is:

```
<?php
class MyClass {
public $myArray = array();

public function updateArray($newValue) {
    $this->myArray[] = $newValue;
}

public function showArray() {
    foreach($this->myArray as $arrayValue) {
        echo "<li>";
        echo $arrayValue;
        echo "</li>";
    }
}

}

$var = new MyClass;

$var->updateArray("Value 1");
$var->updateArray("Value 2");
$var->updateArray("Value 3");

echo $var->showArray();

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Simply use `func_get_args` if you wish to pass the other arguments as string values; otherwise pass an Array of values and Process it. The first Idea could be demonstrated with this snippet:

```
    class MyClass {
        public $myArray = array();

        public function updateArray($newValue) {
            $arguments  = func_get_args();
            if($arguments) {
                foreach ($arguments as $argument) {
                    $this->myArray[] = $argument;
                }
            }
        }

        public function showArray() {
            foreach($this->myArray as $arrayValue) {
                echo "<li>";
                echo $arrayValue;
                echo "</li>";
            }
        }

    }

    $var = new MyClass();

    $var->updateArray("Value 1", "Value2", "Value 3");
    $var->showArray();
```

> The second idea: *passing an Array of values* could be demonstrated by the snippet below:

```
    class MyClass {
        public $myArray = array();

        /**
         * UPDATES THE INTERNAL ARRAY USING WHATEVER VALUES PASSED IN AS ARGUMENT(S)
         * IN THIS CASE, YOU COULD PASS AS MANY ARGUMENTS AS YOU WISH AS STRING-VALUES...
         * @param $newValue
         */
        public function updateArray($newValue) {
            $arguments  = func_get_args();
            if($arguments) {
                foreach ($arguments as $argument) {
                    $this->myArray[] = $argument;
                }
            }
        }

        /**
         * UPDATES THE INTERNAL ARRAY USING A COLLECTION: AN ARRAY OF VALUES
         * @param array $collection
         */
        public function updateArrayFromCollection(array $collection) {
            if($collection) {
                foreach ($collection as $value) {
                    $this->myArray[] = $value;
                }
            }
        }

        public function showArray() {
            foreach($this->myArray as $arrayValue) {
                echo "<li>";
                echo $arrayValue;
                echo "</li>";
            }
        }

    }

    $var = new MyClass();

    $var->updateArrayFromCollection(["Value 1", "Value2", "Value 3"]);
    $var->showArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like that:

```
public function updateArray() {
    if (func_num_args() > 0) {
        $args = func_get_args();
        foreach ($args as $arg) {
            $this->myArray[] = $arg;
        }
    }
}
```

I didn't try the code so it could contains errors.

Comment: Thanks :) That Works

Answer (score 0):

```
public function showArray() {
    foreach($this->myArray as $arrayValue) {
        $array_collect[] =  $arrayValue; 
    }
}
```

Then print

```
$array = Implode (',',$array_collect);
echo $array;
```

arrange collection according to use Implode function